# ServiceStack .net project and log4net issue

Tags: servicestack, log4net

I am trying to set up log4net logging on my .net application. I want to log to a file.

I have looked around on how to set this up and try to resolve this issue for a while so I thought I would just post. I have logging code in three places. It seems to work in two and not in one. I will only include what I think is relevant code.

In my AppHost.cs I have (This writes to my log file correctly)

```
 using log4net;

 ....

 private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("BensLogger");
 public static void Start()
    {
        log.Info("Entering application apphost.");
        new AppHost().Init();
    }

....
```

Next in my Global.asax.cs I have (This also logs to my file correctly)

```
using log4net;

....

private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("BensLogger");
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        log.Info("Entering application global.asax.cs.");
    }

....
```

The log code below from my Service class does not log to the file though.

```
using log4net;
using log4net.Config;

[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "C:\\Users\\balibasic\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\Latest Rewo July 31-2014\\trunk\\RewoServiceLayer\\Log4Net.config", Watch = true)]

....

public class FriendService : Service
    {
        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("BensLogger");

        public object Post(FriendRequestRequestDTO friendRequest)
        {
            log.Info("Entering service.");
        }
    }
....
```

The way I test it is by making a call to the service through code. When I debug and step through I see the logger is initialized and the "isInfoEnabled" property is "true" along with all the other properties for logging levels. Which I take to mean that it should be able to log at that point for all levels.

I don't get any errors in configuration or at runtime that I can see it looks like it tries to log but nothing happens.

My log4net.config file that I reference is here

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net, requirePermission=false" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="example.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </root>
    <logger name="BensLogger">
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </logger>
  </log4net>
  <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

My log file looks like this after I run my application in visual studio and make a call to the service method with the logging code in it.

```
2014-08-04 17:34:54,735 [1] INFO BensLogger - Entering application apphost.
2014-08-04 17:34:54,735 [1] INFO BensLogger - Entering application apphost.
2014-08-04 17:34:55,176 [1] INFO BensLogger - Entering application global.asax.cs.
2014-08-04 17:34:55,176 [1] INFO BensLogger - Entering application global.asax.cs.
```

As you can see it has the messages from the apphost and the global.asax.cs but not the FriendService class.

I can provide more information if I forgot something or if anyone would like to see something else.

Comment: you have (the process has) permissions to write to specified location?

Comment: ignore that, it's the same config file

Comment: Looks like I have figured it out after writing this entire thing out of course...

When I make a call to the service through code it does not log, but if I make a call to the service from outside of the code. For example I used Postman to send a request to my service and then it does log.

Comment: If anyone could tell me why this works like this that would be great